# DrRacket can't write square brackets

Tags: keyboard, racket, square-bracket

I have a problem with my DrRacket.

I can't write `[,],{,}` in DrRacket.

I use the combo `strg+alt+8`, but if I do that in Racket it writes 8.

How can I fix it?

Comment: German keyboard? Windows 8?

Comment: Or Windows 7 perhaps?

Comment: @Tobias Just wanted to acknowledge your comment ("Im using the Logitech G510 :( But I need the quare bracket for my Cond...otherwise its confusing"). Lemme ask on the #racket IRC channel to see if there are any other remedies.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a keyboard configuration issue at your end, so I can't help with that. However, I can say that in Racket, [] and {} are treated the same as (), so you can just use round brackets throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Try using English keyboard configuration on your system. Or you can just use parentheses (). They work the same! :) Good luck.